# VBA to compare columns and fire macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have three columns (ABC) with multiple rows.

I need to check if B is greater than C, and if so to add 1 to C and repeat until the last row.
I'm getting a syntax error, any help much apprecicated!

```
Sub test6()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
If Range("B" & i).Value > ("C" & i).Value Then Range("C" & i).Value 1


Else: End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to show us the code in the original post if you want us to help find the problem.  Also tell us whether there is an error and what line, or what goes wrong with the code.

Comment: Get rid of this line `Else: End If` since you have the if then in one line it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `Else: End If` as Scott Craner mentioned in comment and change `If` statement:

```
If Range("B" & i).Value > Range("C" & i).Value Then Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i).Value + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Egan and Scott!